# Is it possible to search for part the of text using word embeddings?

Tags: gensim, word2vec, word-embedding, doc2vec

I have found successful weighting theme for adding word vectors which seems to work for sentence comparison in my case:

```
query1 = vectorize_query("human cat interaction")
query2 = vectorize_query("people and cats talk")
query3 = vectorize_query("monks predicted frost")
query4 = vectorize_query("man found his feline in the woods")

>>> print(1 - spatial.distance.cosine(query1, query2))
>>> 0.7154500319

>>> print(1 - spatial.distance.cosine(query1, query3))
>>> 0.415183904078  

>>> print(1 - spatial.distance.cosine(query1, query4))
>>> 0.690741014142
```

When I add additional information to the sentence which acts as noise I get decrease:

```
>>> query4 = vectorize_query("man found his feline in the dark woods while picking white mushrooms and watching unicorns")
>>> print(1 - spatial.distance.cosine(query1, query4))
>>> 0.618269123349
```

Are there any ways to deal with additional information when comparing using word vectors? When I know that some subset of the text can provide better match.

---

UPD: edited the code above to make it more clear.

`vectorize_query` in my case does so called smooth inverse frequency weighting, when word vectors from GloVe model (that can be word2vec as well, etc.) are added with weights `a/(a+w)`, where w should be the word frequency. I use there word's inverse tfidf score, i.e. `w = 1/tfidf(word)`. Coefficient `a` is typically taken 1e-3 in this approach. Taking just tfidf score as weight instead of that fraction gives almost similar result, I also played with normalization, etc.

But I wanted to have just "vectorize sentence" in my example to not overload the question as I think it does not depend on how I add word vectors using weighting theme - the problem is only that comparison works best when sentences have approximately the same number of meaning words.

I am aware of another approach when distance between sentence and text is being computed using the sum or mean of minimal pairwise word distances, e.g.
"Obama speaks to the media in Illinois" <-> "The President greets the press in Chicago" where we have `dist = d(Obama, president) + d(speaks, greets) + d(media, press) + d(Chicago, Illinois).` But this approach does not take into account that adjective can change the meaning of noun significantly, etc - which is more or less incorporated in vector models. Words like adjectives  'good', 'bad', 'nice', etc. become noise there, as they match in two texts and contribute as zero or low distances, thus decreasing the distance between sentence and text.

I played a bit with doc2vec models, it seems it was gensim doc2vec implementation and `skip-thoughts` embedding, but in my case (matching short query with much bigger amount of text) I had unsatisfactory results.

Comment: I think you can use [Doc2Vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) to find similarities between different queries.

Comment: What does `vectorize_query()` do? Why does the last `vectorize_query()` calls print a single number in the 0.0 to 1.0 range, while the earlier calls did not?

Comment: @gojomo  I updated the question with explanations

Comment: @Harman I updated the question with explanations

Comment: If you are interested in part-of-speech to trigger similarity (e.g. only interested in nouns and noun phrases and ignore adjectives), you might want to look at sense2vec, which incorporates word classes into the model.  https://explosion.ai/blog/sense2vec-with-spacy ...after which you can weight the word class while performing a dot product across all terms, effectively deboosting what you consider the 'noise'.

Comment: @binarymax Thanks very much for the answer! I was thinking about grammar and experimented a bit with either extraction of noun phrases or extraction of a word which had dependency to noun, etc. So I had both "cleaning worker" (both important) and "very cheap vase" (nothing important except "vase") out of my queries but didn't know what to do with it. I will study this approach, thanks again!

Comment: @Slowpoke you're very welcome.  As this is what you were looking for I made it into an official answer :)  Please let me know if you'd like any more detail.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in part-of-speech to trigger similarity (e.g. only interested in nouns and noun phrases and ignore adjectives), you might want to look at sense2vec, which incorporates word classes into the model. https://explosion.ai/blog/sense2vec-with-spacy ...after which you can weight the word class while performing a dot product across all terms, effectively deboosting what you consider the 'noise'.

Comment: sense2vec looks like abandonware. Any similar, active initiatives?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear your original result, the similarity decreasing when a bunch of words are added, is 'bad' in general. A sentence that says a lot more is a very different sentence!

If that result is specifically bad for your purposes – you need a model that captures whether a sentence says "the same and then more", you'll need to find/invent some other tricks. In particular, you might need a non-symmetric 'contains-similar' measure – so that the longer sentence is still a good match for the shorter one, but *not* vice-versa.

Any shallow, non-grammar-sensitive embedding that's fed by word-vectors will likely have a hard time with single-word reversals-of-meaning, as for example the difference between:

`After all considerations, including the relevant measures of economic, cultural, and foreign-policy progress, historians should conclude that Nixon was one of the very *worst* Presidents`

`After all considerations, including the relevant measures of economic, cultural, and foreign-policy progress, historians should conclude that Nixon was one of the very *best* Presidents`

The words 'worst' and 'best' will already be quite-similar, as they serve the same functional role and appear in the same sorts of contexts, and may only contrast with each other a little in the full-dimensional space. And then their influence may be swamped in the influence of all the other words. Only more sophisticated analyses may highlight their role as reversing the overall import of the sentence.

While it's not yet an option in gensim, there are alternative ways to calculation the "Word Mover's Distance" that report the unmatched 'remainder' after all the easy pairwise-meaning-measuring is finished. While I don't know any prior analysis or code that'd flesh out this idea for your needs, or prove its value, I have a hunch such an analysis might help better discover cases of "says the same and more", or "says mostly the same but with reversal in a few words/aspects".

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer! Hopefully, I do not need such a precision as in your example. I am doing the search trough textual information written by certain people to understand who is more competent in the topic provided a one-sentence query.  That's why I wanted to find the way to compare with some part of the whole massive of text which is the closest possible match, taking to the account that query can consist of a multiple meaning parts, e.g. "to construct nuclear fusor you need physics, but also good skills in winding reels and soldering iron".

Comment: Just searching for keywords proved to be inefficient, especially for the ones who has a *lot* of text associated with them. In your example I may conclude that source is "familiar" with Nixon in some way which satisfies query very well (economic, cultural, including historians).

Comment: You can also think of that as a way to search for *deeply* hidden plagiarism.

Comment: The problem with keyword distances is that they are always lower for the ones who has a lot of data associated with them, I wanted to preserve the relationships between query topics somehow and then to search the corpus.